Висячие указатели
int* ptr = new int(10);
std::cout << "Адрес при создании " << ptr << "\n";
delete ptr;
std::cout << "Адрес после очистки " << ptr << "\n";

После очистки памяти, на которую ссылался указатель его нужно занулить (ptr = nullptr), чтобы он не ссылался на недействительную область памяти, я ведь правильно понял?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
