delete <addressPointer> устанавливает nullptr?
Не знаю, может уже есть похожий вопрос.
И так, учился я пользоваться ссылками и адрессами, и решил посмотреть еще динамическую память.
new, delete.
Первый вопрос, динамическая память это стек или куча(в случаи с указателями):
int* pointer = new int;
*pointer = 150;
// робота с указателем...;
delete pa;

второй вопрос: устанавливает ли delete нашему указателю nullptr или после осовбождение надо установить самому?
более чётко: при создании нашего указателя и по окончанию роботы с ним, мы его очищаем с помощью delete, устанавливаеться ли nullptr. Или если бы мы сделали -
int* pointer = new int;
*pointer = 150;
// робота с указателем
pointer = nullptr;

результат был бы тот же?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Странно, что вы присваиваете выделенную память одной переменной (pointer), а освобождаете pa. Пишите delete pointer - это освободит память. Значение pointer при этом в общем случае не обнуляется (зачем? Разве что в каком-то особо отладочном режиме этим кто-то будет заниматься...). Простое же присвоение nullptr без удаления приводит просто к утечке памяти.

Ошибка, извеняюсь. Но я понял спасибо.
delete pointer;
pointer = nullptr;


new не создает указатель, new выделяет память и создает объект.  А при помощи оператора delete разрушается объект, на который указывает указатель и освобождается занимаемая этим объектом память. и еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1596137

я это и пытался спросить.. но обьяснить не вышло
